# Phonegap Android app - not reading cookie on WIFI?

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have built a Android HTML5 app using Phonegap which uses an iframe to process payments via system on a partner companies server.

The system drops a cookie with an inbox code on the phone which means that once the user has register once - the system uses the cookie to save them re-registering - all worked fine until time for launch and now it will only work on wifi and not on 3G!?

This has all previously worked - so it doesn't make any logical sense to me!  I wondered whether it could be due to a permission change in my manifest file?  (which is below)

Does anybody have any ideas at all?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.phonegap.chillimusicapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >
      <supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:resizeable="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"
  />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
    <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:name=".ChilliMusicAPPActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" > <intent-filter> </intent-filter> </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> <intent-filter> </intent-filter> </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```